# Windows Task Scheduler - a Day before first Sunday of the month

Tags: windows

I need to create a schedule for a task on Windows Task scheduler that triggers a day (i.e. 24 hours) *before* the first Sunday of the month.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if the scheduler can do that, but for clearification: What if the 1. of a month is a Sunday?

Comment: then the previous day i.e. 31st/30th/29th/28th...whichever happens to be the last day of the immediately previous month

Comment: I guess it will have to be a Daily job which targets a PowerShell script which in turn checks if tomorrow is the first Sunday and if it is, execute the real job...Something like $date = Get-Date;
if($date.Day -lt 7 -and $date.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek -eq 'Sunday') {'Execute the real job'}

Comment: I think that's actually not the worst of ideas. Haven't found another way to make a trigger that specific. Maybe if we take into account that "the day before Sunday" is _always_ "Saturday" ... but that "if Sunday is 1." always disrupts my attempts.

Comment: ^^ But maybe that could make your Script easier. A weekly task on Saturdays, only. Then you'd just have to check if it's the last of that month (+1 day => different month) or first saturday in the month ( day < 7? maybe 6? not sure).

Comment: Sounds like that should work. Instead of 30/31 invocations, just 4/5.

Comment: $date = Get-Date;

if(($date.Month -ne $date.AddDays(1).month) -or ($date.Day -lt 7 -and $date.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek -eq 'Sunday')) {
    'Executing...'
}

Comment: Something like that should do the trick. Just give it a try.

Comment: ... turns out $date.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek -eq 'Sunday') check is redundant in my code above.

Comment: Umm yep. If that fails, you messed up your trigger. date+1Day should be a different month to trigger the actual task. Because if today is Saturday and if I add one day, it's a different month, then today is the day before the first Sunday in that month, which happens to also be the 1. of that month. But that's in your first condition. So, yeah, should be fine.